# Selenium sends incomplete text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a problem with Selenium when it comes to use `.sendKeys(text)`. During the automation process, sometimes selenium is sending incomplete strings to the browser, which causes to create incorrect searchs.

i.e. I want to type "MY DROP", and it will type "Y DROP", or "ROP".

It does not always type the same way, so sometimes 2 letters might be missing, and sometimes the whole word is missing.
This only happens to dropdowns, where I have a specific method that handles the dropdown selection, as we are using angular I can't use the selenium select dropdown method.
I already tried to set Thread.Sleeps and waits on the dropdown selection but nothing seems to work, currently this is what I use to select a value:

```
public void select(String item) {
        waitTillClicable();
        WebElement element = getElement();
        openDropDown(element);
        element.sendKeys(item);
        waitResultLoad();
        selectResult(element);
    }
```

This code was working perfectly until the last week. I'm thinking it has something to deal with the new Chrome version 45, as before it was not happening. I also tried to use different chromedriver versions, and running on a Linux machine, but nothing seems to have an effect.

Right now I created a workaround where I keep verifying if the string was typed correctly, and re-typing it until it is correct, but this makes the execution time increased, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: try clicking on the select and then sendKeys. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm already doing this... My problem is after the drop is "opened" and I have to sendKeys.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML.

Comment: To open the dropdown:
`<div label="MyField">
<label class="control-label-data">MyField</label>
 <div class="controlsData controls-row">
 <div class="select2-container span9 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="s2id_autogen7">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice>`  
  
The item selection is at an entirely different html:
`<div class="select2-drop" id="select2-drop">
 <ul class="select2-results">
  <li class="select2-result select2-result-selectable">
   <div class="select2-result-label">
    <span class="select2-match">
    </span>ITEM 1</div></li>`

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `.sendKeys()` to select a value in a `SELECT`? Use the provided methods for a Select: `.selectByIndex(int)`, `.selectByValue(String)`, or `.selectByVisibleText(String)`. Some examples...

```
Select test = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown")));
test.selectByIndex(1);
test.selectByValue("myValue");
test.selectByVisibleText("VisibleText");
```

Comment: "SELECT" doesn't work as we are using a custom dropdown, that's why I created a custom method to select the value.

Answer (score -1):

See if the happens on Firefox driver or IE driver 
The other thing is  the method signature is

```
  public void sendKeys(CharSequence... value)
```

can you try to send it like this sendKeys( "MY","DROP"); instad and see  the result

Hope this may help.
Alan Mehio
London, UK

Comment: The application doesn't work in Firefox and IE. I can only test i Chrome. I tried to use the "sendKeys( "MY","DROP");", but it didn't work.

Comment: what exception do you get ?   uninstall and install   IE and FireFox again